# Recursive method returning undesired value

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a function that needs to return a value when it's done doing some stuff. I won't bore you with the details.
My function calls itself so it's recursive. Now, I want to be able to obtain the resulting value of this function when I call it from elswhere.
So this is the code:

```
public int compute(string[] myarray)
{
    if (hasParantesisBlock)
    {
        // do stuff
        // remove paranthesis block from myarray
        String[] newArray = removeBlockFromArray(myarray);
        // recursive call                   
        compute(newArray);
    }
    else
    {
        // do other stuff obtaining a value
        return value;
    }
    return 0; // if I remove this I get error
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
int myval = compute(myStringArray);
```

I have a string array and I want to remove blocks that are between parentheses from this myStringArray. I do that in my function compute, until there are no more parentheses blocks there. When that happens I want to do a count of the elements of the string array for example (not a good example) and I want to return that value in the main code.

Because of that last "return 0; ", I always receive 0. But if I display the result (value) from inside the recursive method... I get the right value.

And if there are 2 blocks of parentheses in my string array, then I will get 2 returned values of ZERO, if I have 3 blocks, then I will get 3 ZERO results....

I do not want those ZERO results. I only want to return the value obtained when there are no blocks left in the string Array.

So steps are like this:

```
- does it have a block?
   - yes. remove block and recall with changed array
     - does it have a block?
       - yes. remove block and recall with changed array
          - does it have a block?
          - no. RETURN my value (!!! this is the only return I want to receive)
       - standard return
   - standard return
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why doesn't simply writing `return compute(newArray);` work?

Comment: `compute(newArray);` throws the return value away. As Peter says, if you `return` it, it should work - and you won't need the `return 0`, since both cases of the `if` will now return.

Comment: Thank you guys. That solved it. I am going to bed now. It's about time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Peter said,

remove the return 0; return the value of compute(newArray) instead.

(can't comment as i don't have enough rep).

```
public int compute(string[] myarray)
{
    if (hasParantesisBlock)
    {
            // do stuff
            // remove paranthesis block from myarray
            String[] newArray = removeBlockFromArray(myarray);
            // recursive call                   
            return compute(newArray);
    }
    else
    {
          // do other stuff obtaining a value
          return value;
    }
}
```

without viewing the entire code i can see a few possible gotchas. Such as not using the return value in the method. As in

```
return compute(newArray)++;
```

Comment: A few good examples (including the standard Factorial example) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142292/Recursive-methods-in-Csharp

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something obvious.